# Calling a click function independently

Tags: javascript, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm using the following spell checking javascript. The button that opens the spell checker is defined as button and if a icon, image or text is given the matching id, when this is clicked the spell checker opens.

I want to be able to call the spellchecker directly e.g. onclick="openChecker();" i even tried _openChecker() but cannot seem to call the correct function.

https://raw.github.com/LPology/Javascript-PHP-Spell-Checker/master/spellcheck.js

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: try `var mySC = sc.SpellChecker(myOptions); mySC._openChecker();`

Answer (score 0):

The ID property should be unique in the first place so you should not have other elements with the same ID - one of the reasons is what happens to you, you get events triggered when elements with the same ID are clicked. You should fix this and if you do have elements that require the same identificator, you should use a class instead. As for your question you could do something like this:

`$("selector").on("click",function(){ 
     //your code here
});`